# CSharpCompilation.Emit() throwing error while executing Roslyn API

Tags: c#, dll, roslyn

I am trying to build a Dynamically Linked Library (DLL) from Roslyn API which builds a Syntax tree from the raw text input.

However, I am getting an exception on while emitting the result of the compilation.

The exception thrown here is:

> "error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Console' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (Are you missing an assembly reference)"

[image]

---

**.NET Framework used**: 4.7.1

**App Type**: .NET Core 2.0 Console App

**Here is the code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Loader;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit;

namespace RoslynCompileSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string code = @"
                using System;
                namespace RoslynCompileSample
                {
                    public class Writer
                    {
                        public void Write(string message)
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine(message);
                        }
                    }
                }";
            SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code, CSharpParseOptions.Default);

            var syntaxRoot = syntaxTree.GetRoot();
            var MyClass = syntaxRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().First();
            var MyMethod = syntaxRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().First();
            Console.WriteLine(MyClass.Identifier.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(MyMethod.Identifier.ToString());

            string assemblyName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
            MetadataReference[] references = new MetadataReference[]
            {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location)
            };

            CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                assemblyName,
                syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
                references: references,
                options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));



            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);

                if (!result.Success)
                {
                    IEnumerable<Diagnostic> failures = result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic =>
                        diagnostic.IsWarningAsError ||
                        diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);

                    foreach (Diagnostic diagnostic in failures)
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", diagnostic.Id, diagnostic.GetMessage());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());

                    Type type = assembly.GetType("RoslynCompileSample.Writer");
                    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    type.InvokeMember("Write",
                        BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                        null,
                        obj,
                        new object[] { "Hello World" });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Can't seem to figure out, what is the issue. `System.Dll` is already added into the references.

Thanks.

Comment: That's because in .net core, `System.Console` is in its own dll (`System.Console.dll`) to which you need to add reference.

Comment: How to add reference in MetadataReference?

Comment: `MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Users\xyz\.nuget\packages\system.console\4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Console.dll")` is this correct way to do add?

Comment: Well you can add the same way you add other references: `MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Console).Assembly.Location))`

Comment: No, still not fixed :(

Comment: But at least there is some other error now, or the same?

Comment: Getting these errors now, `CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
    CS0012: The type 'Decimal' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

Comment: Well then problem you mentioned in question _is_ fixed and now you just have another one :)

Comment: Hahahahahahahaha @Evk